# SparkR org.apache.spark.SparkException: R worker exited unexpectedly

Tags: apache-spark, sparkr, databricks

I am trying to execute a SparkR `gapply` , essentially when I attempt to run this with my input file limited to about 300k rows it works, however scaling up to about 1.2m rows I get the following recurring exception in the stderr in many executor tasks - roughly 70% of tasks complete while the others failed or killed. The failed ones have the same error output:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: R worker exited unexpectedly (cranshed)
    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RRunner.org$apache$spark$api$r$RRunner$$read(RRunner.scala:240)
    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RRunner$$anon$1.next(RRunner.scala:91)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:409)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.agg_doAggregateWithKeys$(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIterator.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$8$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:395)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.write(BypassMergeSortShuffleWriter.java:125)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:53)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:346)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.io.EOFException
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readInt(DataInputStream.java:392)
    at org.apache.spark.api.r.RRunner.org$apache$spark$api$r$RRunner$$read(RRunner.scala:212)
    ... 16 more
```

What are some tuning parameters to consider apart from assigning more memory? I believe SparkR is not as widely used as PySpark or Scala and sometimes their tuning parameters can be different so any kind of help here would be greatly appreciated.

This is running on a Databricks/AWS cluster - 20 worker nodes, 30.5 GB Memory, 4 Core each.

In our use case the `gapply` function operates at max 10 row-dataframes, splits at max 20 columns into 4 R dataframes which are then fed into a linear optimisation solver using R packages `NlcOptim,quadprog`.

Comment: `gapply` is effectively [`groupByKey`](https://databricks.gitbooks.io/databricks-spark-knowledge-base/content/best_practices/prefer_reducebykey_over_groupbykey.html) so it causes the same problems, and without specific restrictions on the input, just don't scale. The exception you is likely a result of a failure cause by a data skew. R makes it worse, but probably not that much.

Comment: So in theory do you think I could split my input dataframe into N dataframes and then execute N gapply functions sequentially?

Comment: I think it might be useful if you provide some context on what `gapply` is doing. There might be just a better way to solve this.

Comment: Updated the question with (hopefully) helpful info

Comment: Can't you split data before you call `gapply`, and use smaller groups this way?

Comment: No the input groups are as small as they can be, what I want to achieve(linear optimisation) has to be done on each group as a whole

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood you. So `gapply` already receives _10 row-dataframes_ for each group.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170234/discussion-between-and-apo-and-user9613318).

Comment: check & double check that scaling up didn't inadvertently introduce some edge cases in your code that are causing errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use .cache() and trying again sorted out this issue.